# How can I copy only text of a specific colour in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, string, colors, copy-paste

I have a worksheet with a large number of cells containing large amounts of text. Within any particular cell there may be some text that is coloured red. I want to remove that text and copy it to a different column.

I have a VBA function that does this by checking the cell contents character by character but the spreadsheet is quite large and the process slows down to a crawl. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

How exactly are you doing this?  Are you activating cells then reading the data in a loop?  Have you tried [these tips](http://blogs.msdn.com/excel/archive/2009/03/12/excel-vba-performance-coding-best-practices.aspx) on improving macro performance?  If only words (and not specific letters in a given word) are coloured red, could you not create a temporary array out of a block of text (use the space " " as a delimiter) and loop through each word?

Rough ex)

```
blockOfText = "This is a block of text."
myArray = split(blockOfText, " ")
for each str in myArray
    '' If color is red, append to "bad text array" and remove from this one ''
next
'' Then convert the "myArray" back into a string and place back in the cell
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague but it looks like you need have your VBA function check the `.Interior.Color` property of each cell such as `Worksheets("yourname").Cells(rowIndex, colIndex).Interior.Color`

Comment: The problem is that the text in the cell may have black text *and* red text and I want to copy *only* the red text. And also I *think* the color property refers to fill color not text.

Comment: Yes, I misinterpreted your "coloured red" to mean the cell's background fill was red.